# Justify Content for DialogActions in MudBlazor

Tags: mudblazor

In `MudDialog`, I want to set the `MudButton` in `DialogActions` to the center with Justify Content.

It works when I use developer tools in chorme, but how can I set this style in my code.

I want the `MudButton` to be positioned in the middle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the CSS classes that you want to apply to `<DialogActions>` container should be placed in the `ClassActions` attribute of `MudDialog`.

Here in this example, I add the `justify-center` [CSS utility](https://mudblazor.com/utilities/justify-content#class-reference) class  to the `ClassActions` attribute which centres the button in `DialogActions`

```html
<MudDialog @bind-IsVisible="visible" Options="dialogOptions" ClassActions="justify-center">
    <TitleContent>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">
            <MudIcon Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Edit" Class="mr-3" /> Edit rating
        </MudText>
    </TitleContent>
    <DialogContent>
        <p>How awesome are inline dialogs?</p>
        <MudRating @bind-SelectedValue="rating" Class="mt-3" />
    </DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
        <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" OnClick="Submit" Class="px-10">Close</MudButton>
    </DialogActions>
</MudDialog>
```

[MudBlazor Snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wawHFmPQpGfYOQkf)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use [MudSpacer](https://mudblazor.com/components/spacer#basic-usage). It just fills empty space.

So if you want your button centered simply add a `<MudSpacer />` Element before and after the button

```
<MudDialog>
    <DialogContent>
        Dialog Content
    </DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
        <MudSpacer />
        <MudButton Color="Color.Primary" OnClick="Submit">Ok</MudButton>
        <MudSpacer />
    </DialogActions>
</MudDialog>
```

[Snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cEmdvQPmpdqMzldV)

If you would like to have two buttons, one left aligned and one right aligned you can set the MudSpacer between the buttons

```
<MudDialog>
    <DialogContent>
        Dialog Content
    </DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
        <MudButton Color="Color.Secondary" OnClick="Cancel">Cancel</MudButton>
        <MudSpacer />
        <MudButton Color="Color.Primary" OnClick="Submit">Ok</MudButton>
    </DialogActions>
</MudDialog>
```